# Inserting a Python List in Python into an SQL Table

Tags: python, database, sql-insert, mysql-python, python-sockets

I have code that reads from a socket and creates a list called i. The socket is read, the list is created from the socket, the list gets printed then deleted. This gets repeated in a while true loop. Instead of just printing the list, I'd like to insert it into a table in my DB. I already have the cursor and connection established in the code. I was messing around with some other stuff but keep getting errors. I would like to use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO. Thank you very much for the help.

This is an example of what the list will look like. 
'Dec-11-2018,','12:28:43,','iPhone,','alpha,','lib,','lib,','(45.67.67)\n']

My table name is StudentPrototype and it has 7 columns 
Columns - (Date,Time,Device,ID,AP,APGroup,MACAdd)

```
#!/bin/python

import socket
import os, os.path
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 
'StudentTacker');
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
i = []





def ParseArray(l): #parses line in socke
    i.append(l.split()[+0] + '-')  # Gets Day
    i.append(l.split()[+1] + '-')  # Gets Month
    i.append(l.split()[+3] + ',')  # Gets Year
    i.append(l.split()[+2] + ',')  # Gets Time
    i.append(l.split()[-2] + ',')  # Gets Device
    i.append(l.split()[+9] + ',')  # Gets ID
    i.append(l.split()[+18] + ',')  # Gets AP
    i.append(l.split()[+19] + ',')  # Gets AP Group
    i.append(l.split()[+16] + '\n')  # Gets MAC
    # This is where I want to REPLACE INTO my table called StudentTest using list i


    print(i)

    del i[:]





if os.path.exists("/-socket"):
    os.remove("/-socket")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind("/home/socket")
infile = sock.makefile('r')




while True:
    l = sock.recv(4096).decode()
    ParseArray(l)
```

Update: I tried another method that I found on this site for how to insert python lists in a db.

Here is my new code that I used inside my function:

```
def ParseArray(l): #parses line in socke
i.append(l.split()[+0] + '-')  # Gets Day
i.append(l.split()[+1] + '-')  # Gets Month
i.append(l.split()[+3] + ',')  # Gets Year
i.append(l.split()[+2] + ',')  # Gets Time
i.append(l.split()[-2] + ',')  # Gets Device
i.append(l.split()[+9] + ',')  # Gets FSU ID
i.append(l.split()[+18] + ',')  # Gets AP
i.append(l.split()[+19] + ',')  # Gets AP Group
i.append(l.split()[+16] + '\n')  # Gets MAC
#insert line into db else by primary key mac adresss
#update line to db if mac adress doesn't exist
params = ['?' for item in i]
sql    = 'REPLACE INTO SocketTest (month, day, year, time, device, 
Id, ap, ApGroup, MacAdd) VALUES (%s); ' % ', '.join(params)
cur.execute(sql, i)
```

Using that I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./UnixSocketReader9.py", line 55, in <module>
ParseArray(l)
  File "./UnixSocketReader9.py", line 28, in ParseArray
cur.execute(sql, i)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 
  187, in execute
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Please make an attempt with your `REPLACE INTO`. There are many examples on this site and others of Python-MySQL. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We volunteers help those who make earnest efforts. Please do so and report back any specific errors and/or undesired results.

Comment: Since your code uses sockets and MySQLdb, you could add the `python-sockets` and `mysql-python` tags to reach a more appropriate audience.

Comment: Thanks, I tired a bunch but couldn't figure it out, I edited showing the error I was getting when I tried it myself.